# Rewriterule flags and static word redirection issue

Tags: php, .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule account$ account.php [Nc]
    RewriteRule (.+)$ store.php [Nc]
```

When I visit http://localhost/project/account it should be redirected to account.php

If I visit http://localhost/project/sun-glass it should be redirected on store.php

Answer (score 1):

Restrict your last rule for existing files and directories:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule account/?$ account.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . store.php [L]
```